# Time.Timescale Not working with DOTween Animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

My code looks like this.

gameObject.transform.DOMoveY(transform.position.y * -1, animationDuration, false)
.SetEase(easeType).SetUpdate(false).OnComplete(() => {
gameObject.SetActive(false); });

what I want to do here is that, whenever I pause my game Using Time.TimeScale=0,
the animation should also pause.
If anyone can help I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Found The answer apparently I was settings timescale on a different function. :)